# adding text and inserting a literal slash between two columns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am capturing the LVs and VGs.

```
$ lvs 
  LV              VG              Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root            rhel            -wi-ao---- <12.81g                                                    
  swap            rhel            -wi-ao----   1.60g                                                    
  lv_hana_backups vg_hana_backups -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                                    
  lv_hana_data    vg_hana_data    -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                                    
  lv_hana_log     vg_hana_log     -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                                    
  lv_hana_shared  vg_hana_shared  -wi-ao---- <10.00g
```

Piping lvs output into awk piping into tail to only return the columns and lines I need.

`lvs | awk '{print $2$1}' | tail -n +4`

Which outputs...

```
  vg_hana_datalv_hana_data
  vg_hana_loglv_hana_log
  vg_hana_sharedlv_hana_shared
```

I want to insert the text `/dev/` at the beginning of column2 for each line and insert a literal slash '/' between the column2 and column1, so it reads like:

```
/dev/vg_hana_backups/lv_hana_backups
/dev/vg_hana_data/lv_hana_data
/dev/vg_hana_log/lv_hana_log
/dev/vg_hana_shared/lv_hana_shared
```

How would I do that?

Comment: how do you go from the current 3 lines of output to an expected output of 4 lines? please update the question to insure the different data sets match

Answer (score 4):

Using the following to simulate OP's `lvs` output:

```
$ cat lvs.out
  LV              VG              Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root            rhel            -wi-ao---- <12.81g                                    
  swap            rhel            -wi-ao----   1.60g                                    
  lv_hana_backups vg_hana_backups -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                    
  lv_hana_data    vg_hana_data    -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                    
  lv_hana_log     vg_hana_log     -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                    
  lv_hana_shared  vg_hana_shared  -wi-ao---- <10.00g
```

One `awk` idea to replace OP's current `awk ... | tail ...`:

```
cat lvs.out | awk 'NR>=4 { print "/dev/" $2 "/" $1 }'
```

**NOTE:** OP will replace `cat lvs.out |`  with `lvs |`

This generates:

```
/dev/vg_hana_backups/lv_hana_backups
/dev/vg_hana_data/lv_hana_data
/dev/vg_hana_log/lv_hana_log
/dev/vg_hana_shared/lv_hana_shared
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
cat foo | awk '{print "/dev/"$2"/"$1}' | tail -n +4
```

outputs

```
/dev/vg_hana_backups/lv_hana_backups
/dev/vg_hana_data/lv_hana_data
/dev/vg_hana_log/lv_hana_log
/dev/vg_hana_shared/lv_hana_shared
```

Comment: Edited my response, and you were right, it becomes the same answer and yours is better due to `NR>=4`. Will upvote yours, then :)

Answer (score 1):

> How would I do that?

I suggest taking look at [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html) as you want just text as-is inside string simple `%s` will suffice for your needs, let `command` output be

```
  LV              VG              Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root            rhel            -wi-ao---- <12.81g                                                    
  swap            rhel            -wi-ao----   1.60g                                                    
  lv_hana_backups vg_hana_backups -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                                    
  lv_hana_data    vg_hana_data    -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                                    
  lv_hana_log     vg_hana_log     -wi-ao---- <10.00g                                                    
  lv_hana_shared  vg_hana_shared  -wi-ao---- <10.00g
```

then

```
command | awk 'NR>3{printf("/dev/%s/%s\n",$2,$1)}'
```

output is

```
/dev/vg_hana_backups/lv_hana_backups
/dev/vg_hana_data/lv_hana_data
/dev/vg_hana_log/lv_hana_log
/dev/vg_hana_shared/lv_hana_shared
```

Explanation: for lines after 3rd line use formatting print with 2 placeholders (`%s`) to output desired text. Keep in mind to use `\n` as `printf` does not add it automatically as opposed to `print`.

(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)